# Fallback support for javascript promises

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, cross-browser, promise

Our web app uses Angular JS and it's built in $http module. Javascript promises are great... but we need to support a kiosk display running Android 4.2 which doesn't support promises (according to [this](http://caniuse.com/#search=promises)).

Are there shims to make these newer libraries compatible with browsers that don't support promises?

Comment: Promises don't need any support from browser, just use a library or something

Comment: @jfriend00 Then what does it mean when caniuse says that promises are unsupported before Android 4.4.4?

Comment: @SDP: That's talking about JavaScript's promises, which are not the same as Angular's.

Comment: @SDP -it means that a naked browser before 4.4.4 doesn't have promises.  But Angular brings their own support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS already has built-in support for promises, regardless of what the host browser supports.  See the [Angular JS doc for this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

So, you can use the Angular version of promises in any browser, regardless of what promise support the host browser has or doesn't have.  Angular had to do this for their own use because they wanted to use promises, but all installed browsers they wished to run in do not have promise support built-in yet.

---

If there was some reason you wanted a promise library independent of what AngularJS already offers or one with more capabilities, there are many 3rd party libraries available that can be added to any project.  I have the most experience with [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) (which I use for node.js developement), but there are others like [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q), [RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) and [When](https://github.com/cujojs/when) and a whole list [here](https://promisesaplus.com/implementations).

Comment: Thanks for this. So just to be 100% clear: There ARE browsers that do not support promises, but the AngularJS framework has fallbacks already built in to handle them. Correct?

Comment: Disregard... Just saw your comment above. Thanks.